# Identity element of a subgroup. (Basic group theory)

Tags: group-theory

let $G$ be a group and let $A \leq G$ and $B \leq G$. I'm to prove that the set $AB = \{ ab: a\in A, b \in B\} $ is a subgroup of $G$.

Is it sufficient to say that since $A \leq G$ and $B \leq G$, $e_G = e_A = e_B = e_{AB}$ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result is false. For example, consider $G=S_3$, with $A=\{e,(12)\}$ and $B=\{e,(13)\}$, then
$$AB=\{ab:a\in A,b\in B\}=\{e,(12),(13),(132)\}$$
which is not a subgroup of $S_3$, since it doesn't contain $(132)^2=(123)$.

However, the result is true if either $A$ or $B$ is a **normal** subgroup in $G$.

Comment: Perhaps one might note that $A B$ is a subgroup iff $B A \subseteq A B$ iff $A B = B A$.

Comment: Why is it sufficient if A or B is normal?